# What is the difference between Ambari Vs Nifi...also how are these kite,banana used in Ambari or Nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi, hortonworks-data-platform

Please share with an example.Zepllin,Ambari,Nifi,Banana,Kite used soley used without kafka or flume

Answer (score 1):

NiFi is a dataflow management system.  It's job is to acquire or receive data from source systems, do the necessary routing and transformation to data, and deliver to various destination systems.  It does this while allowing you to control the flow of data independently of having to encode this knowledge into the sources or sinks and it does this while supporting interactive command and control through a nice UI and by producing data provenance (think chain of custody for data) which enabled extremely powerful use cases.

Ambari is a deployment vehicle for Applications in the Hadoop ecosystem.